# Mongo Aggregate Group List / Filtered Results

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here my records for mongdb

```
{ "_id" : 1,"userId" : "x",  "name" : "Central", "borough": "Manhattan"},
  { "_id" : 2,"userId" : "x", "name" : "Rock", "borough" : "Queens"},
  { "_id" : 3,"userId" : "y", "name" : "Empire", "borough" : "Brooklyn"},
  { "_id" : 4,"userId" : "y", "name" : "Stana", "borough" : "Manhattan"},
  { "_id" : 5,"userId" : "y", "name" : "Jane", "borough" :"Brooklyn"}
```

how can we take result with aggregate by `userId` field like this

```
[
  { 
    x : [{"_id":1,"name":"Central"},{"_id":2,"name":"Rock"}],
    y:[{ "_id" : 3,"name":"Empire"},{ "_id" : 4,"name":"Stana"},{ "_id" : 5,"name":"Jane"}]
  }
]
```

Comment: your response result is not valid json format, can you correct that.

Comment: it was sample sir, doesnt matter correction, if possible i  need object or array results by Grouped field

Comment: i know that am talking about syntax is not valid, i can not predict how you want result either its array of 2 documents or single documents, what is your requirement from both 1) `[ { x: [], y: [] } ]` 2) `[ { x: [] }, { y: [] } ]`

Comment: Thanks for your suggested path, i revised your post as you suggest path 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$group` by `userId` and construct `docs` array with required fields
- `$group` by null and construct array of `docs` in key-value format
- `$arrayToObject` convert `docs` array to object
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above converted object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$userId",
      docs: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$_id",
          name: "$name"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      docs: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: "$docs"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$docs" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qhyZ44YhQzk)